# Identifying C-variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I found this code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224579/267892), but I just can't figure out what the variables `cSrt` and `result` are!

```
for(int i = 0; i<1000000; i++){
    CC_MD5(cStr, strlen(cStr), result);
    sprintf(cStr, "%02x%02x", result[0], result[1]);
}
```

The compiler is telling me that they are `char` and `unsigned char`, but when I try to run it, it gives me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at the `sprintf`-line.

Have you got any idea what I can do to make this snippet work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cStr` and `result` should be arrays of (unsigned) chars, or pointers to (unsigned) char buffers.

For example

```
char cStr[] = "This is my str";
char result[16];
for( int i=0; i<1000000; i++ )
{
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );
    sprintf(cStr, "%02x%02x", result[0], result[1]);
}
```

Note that `cStr` may be `const`, since it is only read, but `result` should be non-constant buffer, because `CC_MD5` writes the result there.

**Edit:**

Actually, in this case, `cStr` cannot be const, as you write to it in the `sprintf` line, but as far as you only use it in `CC_MD5` it should be OK.

Comment: This sort of worked, it crashed on loop 7 with the error `SIGABRT`. Hard to troubleshoot that.. Thanks though :)

Comment: @Emil - this should not crash, at least not this part of the code.

Comment: It does, though, I pasted the exact code you wrote here into my application, and it crashes at line 6...

Comment: The only warning I get is this: `Passing 'char [16]' to parameter of type 'unsigned char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign` on line 5.

Comment: This can be fixed by using `unsigned char result[16]` instead of `char result[16]`... but should not cause a crash...

Comment: Ah, thanks, that fixed it :) Odd, never seen anything like this before..